# "Read More" button displays on individual Posts

Tags: read-more

**http://blog.swamimamiteas.com**

The "Read More" button works fine here...it redirects to the Post.

But...it shows up again on the individual Posts. And it doesn't even do anything when you click it.

**http://blog.swamimamiteas.com/closer-look-get-clean-chamomile/**

Any ideas why?  I've never seen this happen before.

WordPress 4.0.1

Comment: The button is working on the individual post - it just appears that it's doing nothing because it's taking you to the page you're already on. You can test that by right clicking the "Read more" and opening in a new tab, and you'll see it takes you to the same page. Can you describe how and where the read more button was integrated? Was this working fine at one point? We'll need more details so we can help you troubleshoot. Giving us code also helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

```
global $more;
$more = 0;
```

Was used before

```
the_content();
```

So by removing those 2 lines the post now displays the entire content.